Clarification on what "[id=#]" refers to in Spark Physical Plan Exchange hashpartitioning
While looking through spark physical plans generated by the spark history server log to find any bottle necks in my code, I stumbled across an ID that shows up in a partitioning stage.
My goal is to use the spark history server log to provide meaningful analysis on my spark system performance. With this goal in mind, I am trying to connect spark physical plans to StageIDs which house useful information that I can tie back to my code. Below is a snippet from one of the physical plans.
+- *(2) Sort [Column#46 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(ColumnId#329, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#278]

What exactly does [id=#278] refer to?
I have seen some examples that say this ID is a reference to a specific partition, a stage id, or a plan_id but I have not been able to confirm which one it is.

In my view, it is stage ID generated via Spark codegen process.
This link might be useful for more details:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-CollapseCodegenStages.html

Thank you for providing an answer. I parsed through the number of individual stage IDs that were generated from my code. The specific part of the plan that I am confused on ([id=#]) references IDs that surpass the amount of individual stage IDs. (i.e. there are 16390 stages but in one of the plans references [id=#19163])
Why is there a discrepancy between these two values?
